# RCTBridge in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

If my mobile app has more than one RCTRootView usage. Should I reuse the same RCTBridge or create one for each. Assuming both RCTRootView can be on the same VC or different VC. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is recommended to have only one bridge for the entire mobile app. I will be proving the code for iOS.

I will be creating the bridge in Main Application and will be using everywhere.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate,RCTBridgeDelegate>
         @property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
         @property (strong) RCTBridge *reactBridge;
    @end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

  self.reactBridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];


  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:self.reactBridge moduleName:@"ListViewNetworking" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

**You can access the bridge everywhere just like this.**

```
  AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:appdelegate.reactBridge moduleName:@"ListViewNetworking" initialProperties:nil];
```